# Using apache with hhvm

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I've tried to test hhvm (on my local machine), but did not manage to get it working.

Important side-note: I need to run mod_php and fcgi at the same time. It's not possible to abandon mod_php for me (at least not at the moment).

Using debian 7.8

I managed to install a working version of php over fcgi with my existing mod_php still working. They're both running - one using `Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler`  and the other one using `Server API: CGI/FastCGI`.

I then installed (a precompiled package) of hhvm. No Problem. (Precompiled because I do not wanted to waste time compiling). I startet the server, but I does not use hhvm  - still using php (fcgi).

I've read about the script /usr/share/hhvm/install_fastcgi.sh and tried this. This gives me the following output:

```
Checking if Apache is installed
Detected Apache installation
Looking for custom proxy configuration
No custom proxy configuration found
Checking for enabled proxy_fcgi.load
Not found
Checking for enabled fastcgi.load
Not found
Checking for enabled fcgid.load
Found, checking for loading directives
Detected enabled fcgid.load configuration, setting up integration
Force enabling module hhvm_fcgid.conf
WARNING: Unsupported hhvm_fcgid, not configuring
Restarting apache
Apache is running, restarting
[ ok ] Restarting web server: apache2 ... waiting .
Finished restarting
Finished restarting apache
Checking if Nginx is installed
Nginx not found
```

So configuration did not work.

For fcgid I use the following apache vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerAlias h.path1.local

DocumentRoot /var/www/path1
#SuexecUserGroup user1 user1

#ScriptAlias /awstats/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
#we want specific log file for this server


#ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/path1/$1

<Directory "/var/www/path1">
   FcgidWrapper /var/www/path1_conf_hhvm .php
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler fcgid-script
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride FileInfo All
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Port 8000 is, because apache sits behind a varnish.

No I'm using a wrapper file for fcgi. This only contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
 export PHPRC="/etc/php5/cgi"
 exec /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

I guess that I need to change something here to let is use hhvm instead of php. So I tried to use exec /usr/bin/hhvm - which does not work. I get

```
[warn] [client 127.0.0.1] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: test.php
```

And now I'm lost. How to tell fcgid to use hhvm instead of php? Do I need to change the wrapper script (or abandon it completly and use something else)?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move on apache 2.4 in order to have the missing mods (fastcgi)

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

but moving in 2.4 prevent apache to use libapache2-mod-php5, so I had to use php-fpm. I followed this tutorial (sorry it's in french)

http://www.grafikart.fr/formations/serveur-linux/php-fpm

After this, I installed hhvm like described here

https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/linux

finally, I run the command

```
 sudo hhvm -daemon -c server.ini -p 8080
```

if everything is ok, call somewhere a phpinfo() it should replace your php configuration with hhvm

hope it helps maybe later than naver